# Plugin forms overwrite each other's options

Tags: plugin-development, forms, plugin-options

I am creating my first WP plugin, where I have two forms. Both work correctly, but when I save the information from one, the information from the other disappears.

I'd like to save all options in one array, and use the same group of options for both, but I don't know if it's possible.

main plugin php:

```
<?php

    /*
        Plugin Name: Team-K Shonichi
        ... 
    */

    // DIE
    if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        die( '-1' );
    }

    // Paths
    define("TKSNC_DIR_PATH", dirname(__FILE__));            
    define("TKSNC_URL_PATH", plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ));   
    define("TKSNC_DIR_NAME", basename(TKSNC_DIR_PATH));     

    // Includes
    include_once TKSNC_DIR_PATH . "/inc/tks-create-menus.php";
    include_once TKSNC_DIR_PATH . "/inc/tks-dashboard-tab.php";     // One form is here
    include_once TKSNC_DIR_PATH . "/inc/tks-breadcrumbs-tab.php";   // Other form is here
    include_once TKSNC_DIR_PATH . "/inc/tks-breadcrumbs-code.php";
    include_once TKSNC_DIR_PATH . "/inc/tks-admin-scripts.php";
    include_once TKSNC_DIR_PATH . "/inc/tks-misc-options.php";

    // Register Settings

    add_action( 'admin_init', function() {

        $args = array(
            'type' => 'array',
            'default' => null
        );
    
        register_setting( 'we_are_the_team_k', 'TK_Shonichi_Options', $args );

        if(empty(get_option('TK_Shonichi_Options'))) {
            add_option( 'TK_Shonichi_Options', array() );
        }
    
    });

?>
```

tks-dashboard-tab.php

```
<?php

    function TKS_Dashboard_Output() { ?>

        <div class="">
            <form action="options.php" method="post">
                <?php

                    settings_fields( 'we_are_the_team_k' );
                    do_settings_sections( 'we_are_the_team_k' );

                    $tk = get_option('TK_Shonichi_Options');
                                                                            
                ?>

                <table class="form-table tkTable" role="presentation">

                    <tbody>
                            
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" colspan="2" class="topPD">
                                <strong>
                                    <?php esc_html_e( 'Misc options:', 'teamk-shonichi' ); ?>
                                </strong>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">
                                <label for="TK_Shonichi_Options[catImageField]">
                                    <strong>
                                        <?php esc_html_e( 'Add category image field', 'teamk-shonichi' ); ?>
                                    </strong>
                                </label>
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input id="TK_Shonichi_Options[catImageField]" type="checkbox" name="TK_Shonichi_Options[catImageField]"<?php echo checked( isset($tk['catImageField']), true, false ); ?>>
                                    <span class="slider round"></span>
                                </label>                                
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>

                </table>
                            
                <?php submit_button( 'Save changes', 'primary', 'saveButton', true, null); ?>
     
            </form>

        </div>

    <?php }

?>
```

tks-breadcrumbs-tab.php

```
<?php

    // Create the Breadcrumbs menu page

    function TKS_BreadCrumbs_Output() {

            ?>

            <div class="generalWrp">

                <form action="options.php" method="post">
     
                    <?php

                        settings_fields( 'we_are_the_team_k' );
                        do_settings_sections( 'we_are_the_team_k' );

                        $tk = get_option('TK_Shonichi_Options');

                        // echo '<pre>'; print_r($tk); echo '</pre>';                             
                                                                            
                    ?>

                    <table class="form-table tkTable" role="presentation">

                        <tbody>

                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">
                                    <label for="TK_Shonichi_Options[enable]">
                                        <strong>
                                            <?php esc_html_e( 'Enable Breadcrumbs', 'teamk-shonichi' ); ?>
                                        </strong>
                                    </label>
                                </th>
                                <td>
                                    <label class="switch">
                                        <input id="TK_Shonichi_Options[enable]" type="checkbox" name="TK_Shonichi_Options[enable]"<?php echo checked( isset($tk['enable']), true, false ); ?>>
                                        <span class="slider round"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            rest of options goes here....

                        </tbody>

                    </table>
                            
                    <?php submit_button( 'Save changes', 'primary', 'saveButton', true, null); ?>
     
                </form>

            </div>

            <?php

    }
```

So, when I save the form in tks-dashboard-tab.php the array is:

```
Array
(
    [catImageField] => on
)
```

When I save the form in tks-breadcrumbs-tab.php, the values are saved, but the previous value disappear:

```
Array
(
    [enable] => on
    [type] => WebSite
    [locale] => en_US
    [friendly] => on
    [catImage] => 
)
```

If I save the firts tab, once again:

```
Array
(
    [catImageField] => on
)
```

Can't I have the same options for both forms?

I'm missing something, or is something bad in the code?

Thanks.

Comment: having the same name `TK_Shonichi_Options` for both makes no sense. Rephrase the question to instead be about People instead of forms, and pieces of paper not settings. "Whenever Alice writes on the paper they overwrite Bobs words, can I not have 2 people writing in the same place?". If you want them to have separate values they need to be stored in separate places, WP doesn't know they're from separate forms it isn't alive/self-aware, it has to be told they're different via their names, _there is no sharing_

Comment: and you shouldn't be storing multiple values in an option anyway, serialised/structured data in an option can be dangerous. It's both safer and more convenient to use multiple options, e.g. if you use 1 option to bundle everything up then you can't use the REST API to safely modify it or read the data in JS on the frontend via AJAX

Comment: So, I need to register every variable like:

register_setting( 'we_are_the_team_k', 'One variable');
register_setting( 'we_are_the_team_k', 'two variable');
register_setting( 'we_are_the_team_k', 'trhee variable');

Comment: pretty much yes!